# Cannot find any free Report Viewer that supports .NET 5.0 - What are the options?

Tags: .net-5

I have an Enrollment App which adds/creates enrollees including subjects. The only problem is that when I tried to implement Report Viewer it doesn't support .NET 5.0. I have also considered DevExpress but its not for free. Are there any other options?

Comment: What kind of report are you trying to display specifically?

Comment: Just a simple report ready for printing such as such as printing specific student credentials and their relative subjects to be taken.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please make Razor view which displays your report.

If you want to directly export that report into PDF please use

https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa

Comment: I will try to have a look for that. Is the documentation not that hard to understand?